Regression model detects effects that are much smaller than it was powered to detect
I have a mixed-effects regression model with n=250 in each condition. My power analysis predicted that the model would be able to detect effects larger than Cohen's D = 0.20. However, the model detected ended up identifying three effects that were smaller than d = 0.12. Why might this have happened?

A power analysis should give you output along the lines "if the effect exists and is of size $d$, your study as a $x$% chance of detecting it." But there's no reason why it can't detect an effect of size $<d$, it's just less likely

Power is the probability you reject the null when the alternative is true.  What this does not mean is that if the effect estimate is smaller than the assumed effect from the power calculation then the null will fail to be rejected.
